# Contact form unable to send emails

Tags: drupal, smtp, drupal-modules, sendmail

When I try sending an email with the contact form, I get the following error code:

> Error sending e-mail from cliente@mirodinero.com to stokks@hotmail.it: Error SMTP: The following receivers failed: stokks@hotmail.it
>
> SMTP server error: 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user bed513c

What is the problem? I have googled, and I didn't find a solution. bed513c is the actual user of cliente@mirodinero.com, which I set up in the smtp module administration page.

I still am not able to figure out not even WHY this is happening, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your smtp server is rejecting the sender email address.  For some reason the drupal contact form uses the users supplied email address to send the email.  So, joe blow with the email address of joe@blow.com enters his information in the contact form and hits submit.  Drupal uses his email address of joe@blow.com as the sender and the site administrators email address as the recipient.  My smtp server is very specific, if I authenticate against my smtp server with user jason@mysite.com then the sender always has to be jason@mysite.com.  In the case of the drupal contact form it just doesn't work, my smtp server will reject the sender joe@blow.com and return an error of 5.7.1.  Drupal should have an option to force the contact form to send all email with the same email address but for some strange reason it doesn't.

Comment: Fortunately that's precisely what module [contact_reply_to](http://dgo.to/contact_reply_to) does

Answer (score 0):

Check your drupal system configuration System -> Site Information.
I provided the same email id for both SMTP mail settings and site information. 
The problem got solved.